# Endless "loading" of the page due to JQuery script. How to solve it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, pageload

My page stays in an endless loading state due to my "emoji.js" script (Google Chrome testing). The endless loading disables the "emoji" smileys from appearing and you see them in their text code. But when I hit the "stop" cross button in Chrome...they appear!

It seems to be a dumb issue but I can't figure out how to solve it! All my others JQuery scrips works fine, don't understand...

My page: http://raphaelmartin.olympe.in/pc/music.html

Comment: Post some code please. I can't reproduce that issue on Chrome / Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `livereload`, on a specific port, at the end of the page.

It is injecting code at the end of your page to load this script file:

```
view-source:raphaelmartin.olympe.in:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1
```

If you try to access that file directly you will get the same loading forever problem.

Start by removing it until you sort it out :)

If you view the network traffic of your page, e.g. in Chrome's F12 debugging tools, there is a red entry for this JS file, that has a status of:

```
(failed)
net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the following script is not available:

```
<script src="http://raphaelmartin.olympe.in:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></script>
```

The inspector showed a Latency time of something around 20 and 40 seconds waiting to load `livereload.js`, but with no success.